# Multiple MDI child clients that depends on the my.settings

Tags: vb.net, client, mdichild

I have a multiple client that I get [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?587341-VB2008-NET-3-5-Asynchronous-TcpListener-amp-TcpClient), what I want is to make each settings of the client to depend on my.settings.

I have this code:

```
'Sub to create client
Private Sub AddNewClient()
    Call New frmClient() With {.MdiParent = Me}.Show()
End Sub


'OnLoad Event that  creates the new client
Private Sub MainWindow_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Display a single client window by default.
    Me.AddNewClient()
    Me.AddNewClient()
End Sub



Public Class frmClient
    Private ReadOnly host As String = Environment.MachineName
    Private ReadOnly port As Integer = 3131
    Private WithEvents client As New MessageClient(host, port)
    'And lots and lots of code
End Class
```

I want it to be something like this:

```
'Sub to create client
Private Sub AddNewClient(parameterForIP, parameterForPort)
    Call New frmClient(parameterForIP, parameterForPort) With {.MdiParent = Me}.Show()
End Sub


'OnLoad Event that  creates the new client
Private Sub MainWindow_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Display a single client window by default.
    Me.AddNewClient(my.settings.ipClient1, my.settings.ipPort1)
    Me.AddNewClient(my.settings.ipClient2, my.settings.ipPort2)
End Sub



Public Class frmClient(parameterForIP, parameterForPort)
    Private ReadOnly host As String = parameterForIP
    Private ReadOnly port As Integer = parameterForPort
    Private WithEvents client As New MessageClient(host, port)
    'And lots and lots of code
End Class

'Lots of code follows here
```

It seems that I am missing something, am I?

Update: Base on the code given by `jmcilhinney`, it makes my UI to become like this

[image]

I've used it like this

```
Public Sub AddNewClient(clientIP As String, clientPort As Integer)
    Call New frmClient(clientIP, clientPort) With {.MdiParent = Me}.Show()
End Sub


Private Sub MainWindow_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Display a single client window by default.
    With My.Settings
        Me.AddNewClient(.ipClient1, .portClient1)
        Me.AddNewClient(.ipClient2, .portClient2)
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
Public Class frmClient(parameterForIP, parameterForPort)
    Private ReadOnly host As String = parameterForIP
    Private ReadOnly port As Integer = parameterForPort
    Private WithEvents client As New MessageClient(host, port)
    'And lots and lots of code
End Class
```

would have to be this:

```
Public Class frmClient
    Private ReadOnly host As String
    Private ReadOnly port As Integer
    Private WithEvents client As MessageClient

    Public Sub New(parameterForIP As String, parameterForPort As Integer)
        InitializeComponent()

        host = parameterForIP
        port = parameterForPort
        client = New MessageClient(host, port)
    End Sub

    'And lots and lots of code
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, please see my updated question. My UI becomes empty after applying your code. Do you have any idea sir?

Comment: I missed the required call to `InitializeComponent`.  I've updated the code accordingly.